# Pinescript minutes and seconds plotting incorrectly

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

In pinescript, I have a code to plot CPR lines for the entire day wherein the lines from start to end of day are plotted per the normal Intraday session.
How can I have this for say 16 minutes and 30 seconds?

One_Day = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000

Half_Day = ((1 * 16 * 60 * 1000) + (1 * 30 * 60 * 1000))

The below plots the first 16 minutes and 30 seconds perfectly but fails to do from the second 16 minutes and 30 seconds trading session. So basically the need is to break a trading session to half and thereafter making further cuts to the session. Meaning a 450 minute session can be minimum of 15 minute each to a maximum of 225 minute which will be termed as the half of that scripts trading session in a day.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Test", shorttitle="Test", overlay= true, max_labels_count=500, max_lines_count=500,  max_boxes_count=500)
T0 = "Small font size recommended for mobile app or multiple layout"    
Transparency = input(defval=75) 
i_s_font    = input.string("normal",       "Font size", tooltip = T0, options = ["tiny", "small",  "normal", "large", "huge"])
tointeger    = input.int(defval = 1, title = "To Integer")

i_timeZone = input('GMT+05:30')
f_print(_txt) =>
    var _lbl = label.new(bar_index, ta.highest(10)[1], _txt, xloc.bar_index, yloc.price, #00000000, label.style_none, color.black, size.tiny, text.align_left)
    label.set_xy(_lbl, bar_index, ta.highest(10)[1])
    label.set_text(_lbl, _txt)

// f_print(tostring(hour(timenow), "00:") + tostring(minute(timenow), "00:") + tostring(second(timenow), "00") + " (Exchange)\n")
// f_print(tostring(hour(timenow, i_timeZone), "00:") + tostring(minute(timenow, i_timeZone), "00:") + tostring(second(timenow, i_timeZone), "00") + " (Input: " + i_timeZone + ")")
f_print(str.tostring(dayofmonth(timenow, i_timeZone), '00-') + str.tostring(month(timenow, i_timeZone), '00-') + str.tostring(year(timenow, i_timeZone), '00'))



// ============================ Time Function { ================


is_newbar(res) =>
    ch = 0
    if(res == 'Y')
        t  = year(time('D'))
        ch := ta.change(t) != 0 ? 1 : 0
    else
        t = time(res)
        ch := ta.change(t) != 0 ? 1 : 0
    ch



// ============================ Time Function } ================

Label_Color         = input.color(defval=color.new(color.white,100),    title='Label_Color' )

Want_Daily          = input.bool(defval=true,                           title='Daily',      inline='Daily'      )
Want_Daily_Lines    = input.bool(defval=true,                           title='Lines',      inline='Daily'      )
Daily_Color         = input.color(defval=color.new(color.blue, 85),     title='Color',      inline='Daily'      )
Daily_Width         = input.int(  defval=1,                             title='Width',      inline='Daily'      )
Daily_HL_Color         = input.color(defval=color.new(color.red, 85),     title='Color',      inline='Daily'      ) 
Daily_LL_Color         = input.color(defval=color.new(color.red, 85),     title='Color',      inline='Daily'      )
  
Want_W188         = input.bool(defval=false,                          title='W188',     inline='W188'     )
Want_W188_Lines   = input.bool(defval=false,                          title='Lines',      inline='W188'     )
W188_Color        = input.color(defval=color.new(color.orange, 85),   title='Color',      inline='W188'     )
W188_Width        = input.int(  defval=1,                             title='Width',      inline='W188'     )
W188_HL_Color        = input.color(defval=color.new(color.orange, 85),   title='Color',      inline='W188'     )    
W188_LL_Color        = input.color(defval=color.new(color.orange, 85),   title='Color',      inline='W188'     )

    
    
Next_CPR(TF, BG_Color, HL_Color, LL_Color, Width, Lines)=>  

    // *********  Making Pivot  { ********
    PDH     = request.security(syminfo.ticker, TF, high[1]  , barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
    PDL     = request.security(syminfo.ticker, TF, low[1]   , barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
    PDC     = request.security(syminfo.ticker, TF, close[1] , barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
    PDR     = (PDH - PDL)
    Pivot   = (PDH + PDL + PDC)/3
    
    // *********  Drawing Pivot  { ********
    var Bars      = 0, Bars  += 1
    var Line_Size = 0

    var label Label_Pivot = na
    Half_Day       = (12 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
    ONE_DAY       = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 
    
    END_POINT     =    TF=="188"  ? Half_Day    
                     : TF=="D"  ? ONE_DAY   

    // if dayofmonth!=dayofmonth[1]
    if is_newbar(TF)
        Bars       := 1
        Line_Size  := math.min( Bars[1], 450 )
        
        if Lines
            line.new(time, Pivot , time+END_POINT, Pivot , color=color.fuchsia, xloc=xloc.bar_time, width=Width ), 
            Label_Pivot := label.new(bar_index+1, Pivot , color=Label_Color, textcolor=color.fuchsia, style=label.style_label_left, text=str.tostring(TF + '_' + 'PIV' + str.tostring(Pivot, format.mintick)) + ' ', size=i_s_font)
            label.set_x(Label_Pivot, bar_index+1)
    
// *********  Drawing Pivot  } ********
    
if Want_Daily   
    Next_CPR('75',  Daily_Color,   Daily_HL_Color, Daily_LL_Color, Daily_Width,       Want_Daily_Lines    ) 
if Want_W188    
    Next_CPR('188',  W188_Color,   W188_HL_Color, W188_LL_Color, W188_Width,      Want_W188_Lines   )
```

Comment: Can you share your code ? The error is not on your One_Min calculation formula.

Comment: @G.Lebret original question has been edited with the code. Thanks